# Debugging Going Too Far Into My Code

Tags: c++, debugging

I am currently using Visual Studio 2013. I've never used the debugger for my C++ code before, but I used to use it all the time for programming my MSP430. Anyways, I'm trying to get back into programming and trying to use the debugger to step through my code and follow the logic of my if/else statements. When I try to use the debugger to do this, once it begins going into all of the prewritten C++ code for terms such as if, #include, ect. I am trying to get my debugger to ignore all of the standard C++ behind the scenes details, and just step through my code. I messed with Microsoft "My Code Only" feature, but can't seem to get it to do what I desire. Worst case, I guess I have to set a breakpoint after after line I want to go through, but was curious if there was an easier method. Thanks!

UPDATE:

Here is the example code I am using to test your suggestions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

cout << "line one\n";
cout << "line one\n";
cout << "line one\n";
cout << "line one\n";
cout << "line one\n";
cout << "line one\n";
cout << "line one\n";
cout << "line one\n\n";

string input;
cin >> input;

cout << "line one";
cout << "line one";
cout << "line one";
return 0;
}
```

It's nothing pretty, but I'm trying to just step from the first cout statement, see it displayed in my console window, click a button, have it display the next cout statement, repeat, well repeatedly.

I'm sure I'm just not implementing the suggestions correctly. When I try the step out method, it ends up running all of my cout statements. Is this just because I'm trying to do a cout operation, instead of a logic tree, such as if/whiles/ ect?

Here's the illogical mess I'm actually trying to use this method to trace my path through the logic. It's pretty bad code, but before I scrap it and rewrite it, I was trying to figure out how to step through it and trace the mess.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

string action;
bool running = 1;
int turn = 1;

while (running){
    //display map

    if (turn == 1){
    //ask for user input
    cout << "Choose a planet (ex: A1 or D4) or END turn: ";
    cin >> action;

    if (action == "END"){

        if (turn == 1){
            turn = 2;
        }
        else {
            turn = 1;
        }

    }
    }
    else{
        cout << "It is not your turn";
        turn = 2;
    }

    //change players turn
}
return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to step through my nested conditionals, because when I run the code it just prints "It is not your turn" for ever. I'm pretty sure I know the real reason it does this, but debugging this snippets not the purpose of the question. :)

Comment: use "step out" when stepping instructions at a "high level" otherwise you'll end up into operator overrides and function calls

Comment: I updated my answer, there might be a missing piece: "Debug" mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When stepping through the code with MSVC debugger you usually have two options (to be used after setting a breakpoint or having your debugger started and your program paused somehow):

- Step into (shortcut F11)
- Step out  (shortcut F10)

the first enters in detail into function calls, operator overrides, object construction and doesn't leave an instruction until everything has been "stepped through", while the latter is what you want: a "high level" overview that just skips everything in which an instruction can be decomposed and "jumps" to the next instruction.

The "Just my code" used to be a managed-feature only but [it seems they've enabled it for native C++ as well](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/06/26/just-my-code-for-c-in-vs-2013.aspx). This can be useful to avoid pestering the stack trace with lots of unnecessary entries, but the step-in and step-out mechanism still holds.

---

Edit: the above works **IFF** your app is compiled in debug mode. Release mode is an optimized version for.. well.. releasing programs to the end-users. That means it won't have debugging information and thus setting breakpoints won't work as expected.

For the code above:

1. Make sure you're compiling in debug mode (you can change this by going into the project properties)
2. Put a breakpoint on the first statement of your main() function
3. Launch the debugger
4. When the execution stops on the line you put the breakpoint into, press F10 to step to the next instruction

Notice that the execution will be passed to the program when you step over a console input operation to let you digit something on the terminal screen. It will resume in the debugger as soon as you enter the newline character.

Comment: This step by method works great! I just wasn't completely interpreting what was being said correctly by everyone earlier. Also by getting to follow the path, my problem with my code was exactly what I expected, but thanks to everyone's help I can use my debugger properly! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to just "stepping out" immediately after stepping into an operator or new or an accessor that is not of interest, there is also a context menu item "Step into ..." that will bring up a dialog asking which function you actually want to step into. When this works (my experience is that it is often a bit flakey), it will allow you to completely bypass other getters, operators, etc., that are used before the function call of interest is called.

Sometimes, however, the simplest thing is to set a breakpoint in the function that you want to step into and then Continue. I find this the best approach if I'm needing to do it repeatedly.